# Evaluating the intersection point with a vertical line involved

Tags: c++, function, return-value

Here is a function returning the intersection point between two lines defined by points `p0, p1` and `p2, p3`:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <iostream>

struct Point{
    Point(int xx, int yy): x(xx), y(yy) { }
int x;
int y;
};

// find the intersection of two lines
Point intersectPoint(Point& p0, Point& p1, Point& p2, Point& p3){
    // line formed by p0p1
    double dx1 = p1.x - p0.x;
    double dy1 = p1.y - p0.y;
    double m1 = dy1 / dx1;
    double c1 = p1.y - m1 * p1.x;
    cout <<"m1: "<< m1 <<'\n'; 
    // line formed by p2p3
    double dx2 = p3.x - p2.x;
    double dy2 = p3.y - p2.y;
    double m2 = dy2 / dx2;
    double c2 = p3.y - m1 * p3.x;
    cout <<"m2: "<< m2 <<'\n';
    // find intersection point
    double epsilon = 1e-6;
    // (-1,-1) represents no intersection 
    if (abs(m1 - m2) < epsilon) return Point(-1,-1);
    else{
       double interX = (c2 - c1) / (m1 - m2);
       double interY = m1 * interX + c1;
       cout <<"(interX, interY): "<< interX <<", "<< interY <<'\n';
       return Point(interX, interY);
   }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){ 
    Point verticalStart(100, 100);
    Point verticalEnd(100,300);

    Point horizontalStart(50,200);
    Point horizontalEnd(150,200);

    Point intersection = intersectPoint(horizontalStart ,horizontalEnd, verticalStart, verticalEnd);
    cout <<"returned value: \n"; 
    cout << "( "<< intersection.x <<", "<< intersection.y <<" )\n"; 

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In the case of intersection between vertical and horizontal I get an output:

```
m1: 0
m2: 1.#inf
(interX, interY): -0, 200
returned value:
( 0, 200 )
```

### Question:

How to handle this case, so that the function returns valid points of intersection?

Note: the code is compiled on MVS2010.

Comment: Treat it as a special case.  Try drawing a picture; you'll see It's actually much easier than the math for the general case.

Comment: A vertical line  (`x = k`) has infinite slope and can't be described as a linear equation `y = kx + m`. You need to treat them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not to use slope-intercept representation, i.e.: `y = a*x + b` but a vector-parametric representation:

```
Pa = (P1-P0)*t + P0
Pb = (P3-P2)*u + P2
```

In this way the lines `x = k` do have a representation.

Solve the system for the variables `t` and `u` (2 variables, two equations, for the two coordinates `x` and `y`) where `Pa = Pb` (the intersection point) and back-substitute in one of these equations to get the intersection point.